# Java 1.3 library for web service

Tags: java

I have Java 1.3 application and I need to connect them with web service. Is it possible to find some (.jar) library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can use [apache-axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html)

Comment: I need to add some additional library or apache-axis is all that I need.

Comment: please check this at [Installing Axis and Using this Guide](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html)